# MongoDB insert object into array if not exists

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on an app that manages the voting on polls by users. I use MongoDB as DB. (I am a newbie)
My DB is structured as follows:

```json
[
  {
    "question_id": "0001",
    "text": "What's your favourite color ? ",
    "answers": [
      {
        "_id": "872ffaskdfba23jdafs",
        "text": "Blue",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "u0001",
          "nickname": "Paul"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "7832ab28b879293fabb2",
        "text": "Red",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "u0002",
          "nickname": "Eric"
        }
      },
      {
        "_id": "664oahh229s0f829323av",
        "text": "Red",
        "user": {
          "user_id": "u0003",
          "nickname": "Johhny"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Users can leave a maximum of answer for each question; so, for example, users Paul,Eric and Johhny can't vote anymore since their Id's are already present inside 'answers' array.

How could achieve this kind of control with MongoDB ?

Comment: Or do you want to just update the answer with the new response?  E.g., to allow a user to correct their previous answer, or maybe they changed their mind.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $reduce to achieve the behaviour.

1. create a union of the original array and the element you want to add
2. iterate the created union through `$reduce`, append the current element if the user_id is not already exists in our accumulator result; otherwise keep the accumulator result

```js
db.collection.update({}, [
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "answers": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$answers",
              [
                <answer object that you want to insert>
              ]
            ]
          },
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$not": {
                  "$in": [
                    "$$this.user.user_id",
                    "$$value.user.user_id"
                  ]
                }
              },
              "then": {
                "$concatArrays": [
                  "$$value",
                  [
                    "$$this"
                  ]
                ]
              },
              "else": "$$value"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

Here is the [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/-ebBvXgZ3Ud) for your reference